# cmdlet for getting information about which computer locks out AD account

Tags: powershell, events, event-log, windows-server, user-accounts

I need to find out which computer is calling for locking out my account. I can do it in GUI by opening the event viewer and finding a log event in security log, but that's time consuming and since in our environment this does happen very frequently, I need a faster solution. I wrote this command:

`Get-EventLog security -ComputerName DC -InstanceId 4740 | ? {$_.Message -like "MyUserName"} | FL`

I tried also `-match` instead of `-like` but neither gave any results. Anyone knows which operator to use to get what I need?

Comment: Use [altools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18465) and consider ServerFault instead of SO, as account lockout problems are (usually) not programming related questons.

Comment: Well it's a question about how to use powershell to get the information, not how to get it generally, that's why I chose SO. I can't use any software not already present on the server. I'm in a customer's environment, I can't install or use any software I want.

Answer (score 0):

Like @vonPryz I would normally use the altools, but it responds with the DC the account was locked out on and then I came across the code below at https://thesysadminchannel.com/get-account-lock-out-source-powershell/ looks like just the ticket, one of the prerequisites is to allow remote event view access on the DC's to be queried.

Code from the site copied below, should it go offline, all credit to Paul at the SysAdmin Channel:

```
#requires -Module ActiveDirectory
#Import-Module ActiveDirectory -EA Stop

Function Get-AccountLockoutStatus {
<#
.Synopsis
This will iterate through all your domain controllers by default and checks for event 4740 in event viewer. To use this, you must dot source the file and call the function.
For updated help and examples refer to -Online version.


.DESCRIPTION
This will go through all domain controllers by default and check to see if there are event ID for lockouts and display the information in table with Username, Time, Computername and CallerComputer.
For updated help and examples refer to -Online version.


.NOTES  
Name: Get-AccountLockoutStatus
Author: The Sysadmin Channel
Version: 1.01
DateCreated: 2017-Apr-09
DateUpdated: 2017-Apr-09

.LINK
https://thesysadminchannel.com/get-account-lock-out-source-powershell -


.PARAMETER ComputerName
By default all domain controllers are checked. If a computername is specified, it will check only that.

.PARAMETER Username
If a username is specified, it will only output events for that username.

.PARAMETER DaysFromToday
This will set the number of days to check in the event logs.  Default is 3 days.

.EXAMPLE
Get-AccountLockoutStatus

Description:
Will generate a list of lockout events on all domain controllers.

.EXAMPLE
Get-AccountLockoutStatus -ComputerName DC01, DC02

Description:
Will generate a list of lockout events on DC01 and DC02.

.EXAMPLE
Get-AccountLockoutStatus -Username Username

Description:
Will generate a list of lockout events on all domain controllers and filter that specific user.

.EXAMPLE
Get-AccountLockoutStatus -DaysFromToday 2

Description:
Will generate a list of lockout events on all domain controllers going back only 2 days.

#>

[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(
        ValueFromPipeline=$true,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
        Position=0)]

    [string[]]     $ComputerName = (Get-ADDomainController -Filter * |  select -ExpandProperty Name),

    [Parameter()]
    [string]       $Username,

    [Parameter()]
    [int]          $DaysFromToday = 3

)


BEGIN {
    $Object = @()
}

PROCESS {
    Foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
        try {
            $EventID = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $Computer -FilterHashtable @{Logname = 'Security'; ID = 4740; StartTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysFromToday)} -EA 0
            Foreach ($Event in $EventID) {
                $Properties = @{Computername   = $Computer
                                Time           = $Event.TimeCreated
                                Username       = $Event.Properties.value[0]
                                CallerComputer = $Event.Properties.value[1]
                                }
                $Object += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties | Select ComputerName, Username, Time, CallerComputer
            }

        } catch {
            $ErrorMessage = $Computer + " Error: " + $_.Exception.Message

        } finally {
            if ($Username) {
                    Write-Output $Object | Where-Object {$_.Username -eq $Username}
                } else {
                    Write-Output $Object
            }
            $Object = $null
        }

    }

}     


END {}

}
```